# AutoHotKey Help, matching character and replacing

Tags: autohotkey

My save feature, note I do not want to know better ways to save it or corrections to my save code, I just need help on the part where I need it to automatically remove additional non required/old brackets generated on save:
Here's the save button:

```
buttonSave:
FileAppend,
(
nprocess,exist, %Input%
nprocess,priority, %Input%, %PriorInput% 
}
), C:\Users\%A_UserName%\Desktop\AutoSetup\Settings.ahk
MsgBox, 0, Saved, %PriorInput% Priority to %Input% has been saved.
```

How can I get AutoHotkey to find `}` and remove any matching the char `}` and then add one `}` at the very end of the file, and have this looped?

I have a save feature and the output is this:

```
loop
{
process,exist, Steam.exe
process,priority, Steam.exe, 
}
process,exist, Steam.exe 
process,priority, Steam.exe, 
}
```

I want it to find the end `}` and the middle `}` remove both of them and then add a single `}` at the very end. If you save, it always adds a bracket at the bottom.

Comment: For example, if I had that in the settings file, saved a new program it would add this: 
process,exist, something.exe
process,priority, something.exe
} So it would add that to the current code I have above

Comment: how about showing a very short example (few lines) of the pre and post processed file...

Comment: Doing it right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    buttonSave:
FileRead, Contents, C:\Users\%A_UserName%\Desktop\AutoSetup\Settings.ahk
if not ErrorLevel ; Successfully loaded
{
    StringTrimRight, Contents, Contents, 1  ; remove the end }
    FileAppend, %Contents%, C:\Users\%A_UserName%\Desktop\AutoSetup\Temp.ahk
    Contents =  ; Free the memory
}
FileAppend,
(
process,exist, %Input%
process,priority, %Input%, %PriorInput% 
}
), C:\Users\%A_UserName%\Desktop\AutoSetup\Temp.ahk
FileMove, C:\Users\%A_UserName%\Desktop\AutoSetup\Temp.ahk, C:\Users\%A_UserName%\Desktop\AutoSetup\Settings.ahk, 1  ; overwrite existing file
; Run, edit C:\Users\%A_UserName%\Desktop\AutoSetup\Settings.ahk
MsgBox, 0, Saved, %PriorInput% Priority to %Input% has been saved.
; reload  ; if Settings.ahk is included in this script
return
```

Comment: Thank you so much, haven't tried it yet, but it looks perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use something like this (The loop causes high CPU utilization):

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force
#Persistent

Menu, Tray, Add
Menu, Tray, Add, Add Process, Add_Process
Menu, Tray, Default, Add Process ; doubleclick the tray icon to add a new process

SetTimer, set_priority, 500
return

set_priority:
Process,exist, Notepad.exe
Process,priority, Notepad.exe, L
; Add Process
return

Add_Process:
InputBox, ProcessName, ProcessName, Enter a Process.
if !ErrorLevel
InputBox, priority, priority, Enter a priority.
if !ErrorLevel
{
    text =
    (       
    Process,exist, %ProcessName%.exe
    Process,priority, %ProcessName%.exe, %priority%
    ; Add Process
    )
    FileRead, Contents, %A_ScriptFullPath%
    if not ErrorLevel ; Successfully loaded
    {
        StringReplace, Contents, Contents, `; Add Process, %text% 
        FileAppend, %Contents%, %A_ScriptDir%\Temp.ahk
        Contents =  ; Free the memory
    }
    FileMove, %A_ScriptDir%\Temp.ahk, %A_ScriptFullPath%, 1  ; overwrite existing file
    reload
}
return
```

Comment: No, I have a fully functional way to add a process, I just needed to know how to find the saved settings file and remove the extra brackets that were automatically generated on save.

Comment: I edited my post now including how my save works, I don't think I need to really add as far back as the entire gui interface for processes adding though.